# Can I move HUD info on PokerTracker?

Tags: online, poker-tools, hud

I have started using [PokerTracker](http://www.pokertracker.com/) and their HUD info when playing on [PokerStars](http://www.pokerstars.com/).  The HUD info appears automatically over or near the players' icons around the table.

I would have liked to move each separate HUD info to whereever I fancied, for example further away from the table and each other.  Is this possible?  I have looked through most of the settings and such on PokerTracker, but can't seem to find a way.

Comment: While Poker.SE is still in beta and therefore we want as many questions as possible, it would be best if they were actually about poker. Tweaking poker software doesn't really qualify.

Comment: @RaduMurzea I disagree, if we are going to have sections for poker-tools and huds, why should we not have questions on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Poker Tracker myself, I use HEM2.

In that you simply right click and hold the button down while you drag it into the new position. Not sure if its the same though.

A quick google suggests that you ctrl+click and drag.

[Moving HUD](https://www.pokertracker.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=43586)

As suggested by Toby in the comments below, more information can be found here:

[Poker Tracker Guide](http://pokertracker.com/guides/PT4/hud)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work.  I tried the same with the left mouse button, but that did not work either.

Comment: Odd as a quick Google search said that you can just drag them as well!

Comment: @Halvard I have updated my answer have a look!

Comment: Ctrl + click did the trick :)

Comment: More info here http://www.pokertracker.com/guides/PT4/hud

Comment: Toby is correct, this specifically leads to http://www.pokertracker.com/guides/PT4/hud/basic-hud-guide#positioning-hud-elements which in detail describes Gaz' answer and even a second way of doing it (that works too!).